# AngularJS directive for Progress Flow

Tags: javascript, angularjs, progress-bar, workflow, angular2-directives

looking for some advice on if there are any existing AngularJS directives for a progress flow like this:

[image]

The closest things I've come across are progress bars, which are mostly shown for things loading or updating.  I want to code something that shows Stages and the progress to completion.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Something like this? https://github.com/angular-wizard/angular-wizard